# Environment.CurrentDirectory in Resources

Tags: c#

I'm trying to put this string in my resources:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory + \\Server Files\\
```

But whenever I load the string, the Environment.CurrentDirectory part is shown as normal text instead of the current directory path :(.

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(Resources.ServerFilesLocation); // Doesn't give me a path, but just plain text.
```

Comment: You need to think this through for a bit.  How do you expect a value that's *heavily* dependent on the runtime environment, like where the app got installed, to be still accurate when you freeze its value into a resource string?  This can't work.

Comment: Awh, so there's no way this will work :(?

Comment: A string in resources is just that — a string. It is not compiled and not interpreted. The resource manager loads it as-is and returns it to you. The thing you want can be achieved by putting a format string in resources and formatting it with String.Format at runtime.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy How would I go about doing that? I've never done something like that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any runtime environment value cannot be stored as a string in resources. What you should do is create a layer between. Something like:

```
static class ResourceManager
{
    public static string ServerFilesLocation { 
        get { 
            return String.Format(Resources.ServerFilesDirectory, Environment.CurrentDirectory);
            // ServerFilesDirectory = "{0}\\Server Files\\" or something similar
        } 
    }
}
```

And use it like: `Console.WriteLine(ResourceManager.ServerFilesLocation);`